# UIDatePicker show today's date as "Today" to User (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker

I have a basic DatePicker setup showing the user date selections with a format of "Tue Sep 6", "Wed Sep 7", "Thu Sep 8", etc.  I would like to make it more user friendly and if it's today's date show "Today" instead of the date.  So if today is indeed Tue Sep 6, then the wheel would show something custom like "Today Sep 6", "Tomorrow Wed Sep 7", "Thu Sep 8", etc.

I know how to check what today's date is.  I don't know if it's possible to swap out a row or two in a DatePicker or how to do it if it's possible.

If a custom Picker is the only approach, is there any pre-typed out arrays of all the dates out there that I could copy so I don't have to type them all out myself (ugh)?  I googled this to find help here but didn't find anything.

Any thoughts on how to best figure out this problem are greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: What format is your datepicker?  If it is "time and date" then the default is to show "today".  If it is date only then you will need to create a custom picker

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I clarified to make it clearer that this is about customization beyond just "Today".

Comment: Is it a date/time picker or just a date picker?

Comment: It only shows the date.  I'm not sure if I understand the question because a date/time picker and a date picker are both UIDatePicker.  Right?

Comment: yes, but a date only picker has three reels - date, month, year, so it is hard to show "today", "yesterday" etc.  A Date/Time picker (Still a UIDatePicker) shows a single reel for the date, then separate reels for hours, minutes and am/pm, so it can show "today" (But it doesn't show yesterday/tomorrow) etc.  To get what you want you will need to use a custom UIPicker, but even that is tricky since a UIDatePicker is effectively endless; you can move forward and backward limited only by the date limit properties while a standard UIPicker needs to have a fixed row count

Comment: Good points.  I actually ended up going with the Custom Picker approach.  It ended up being a bit more work, but it has more straightforward ways to customize it.

Answer (score 1):

Select the `DatePicker` in your `storyboard` and add the key path 'highlightsToday' of type 'Boolean' in the user defined runtime attributes, make sure the value is checked. This should replace today's date in the date picker to 'Today'

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that idea Z.Hung.  I am actually looking to do something even more custom than this.  I clarified this in my question.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible, i have seen that anywhere  but not sure is for `UIPickerView` or `UIDatePicker`,
 `datePicker` is one type of `UIView` and can be modified , so what you need to do is take `UILabel` and add subview to Date picker and set text accordingly

Comment: That is an interesting idea.  I'm not sure how to quite do that yet, but will try to play around with it and figure it out.

Comment: I actually ended up going with the Custom Picker approach.  It ended up being a bit more work, but it has more straightforward ways to customize it.